# how to fill empty multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, push

I want to fill an empty array by using the function `array_push`, but I got an error that parameter 1 expected to be array but null is given in, here is my code :

```
public $docs = array("ant ant bee", "dog bee dog hog dog ant dog", "cat gnu eel fox");

public function terms(){

    $temp = array();
    $terms = array(array());
    $docs = $this->docs;

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($docs); $i++){

        $temp[$i] = preg_split('/ /', $docs[$i], null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    }           

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($temp); $i++){

        for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($temp[$i]); $j++){

            for($k = 0; $k < sizeof($temp[$i]); $k++){

                if($temp[$i][$j] != $terms[$i][$k])

                    array_push($terms[$i], $temp[$i][$k]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $terms;
}
}
```

Comment: What result do you want?  This looks way overly complex.

Comment: you want every new element ( separated by spaces ) to be in a new level of array? how many levels do you want? can't really get what do you wanna do xd

Comment: The error is pretty obvious, just follow your code and you will see that `$terms[1]` is not set.

Comment: @aleation in `$temp` i want to store the docs strings after splitting them, then in `$terms` i want to store from each sub-array the unique strings, so every duplicated string should stored once for each sub-array

Comment: @user3194430 You should add what you want the resulting array to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment about expected result, this should do it or be extremely close:

```
foreach($this->docs as $value) {
    $terms[] = array_unique(array_filter(explode(' ', $value)));
}    
return $terms;
```

Comment: its really simple and effective

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are doing exactly with all those loops, but your current problem is easily solved by changing:

```
array_push($terms[$i], $temp[$i][$k]);
```

to:

```
$terms[$i][] = $temp[$i][$k];
```

This does the same thing as `array_push()` with the difference that `$terms[$i]` is automatically created if it does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

it can be achieved as follow

```
function terms(){   
    $docs = array("ant ant bee", "dog bee dog hog dog ant dog", "cat gnu eel fox");
    $temp = array();
    $terms = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($docs); $i++){
        $temp[$i] = preg_split('/ /', $docs[$i], null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    } 
    foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
        $temp[$key] = array_unique($value); 
    } 
    return $temp; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that the declaration `$terms = array(array());` does what you want....

**Solution 1: initialize $terms first**

```
$terms = array();

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($docs); $i++){
    $terms[$i] = array();
}
```

Or better: Insert

```
$terms[$i] = array();
```

into your existing loop: either the loop where you initialize `$temp`, or the second `for($i...)` loop, just before `for($j ...)`

**Solution 2: test terms[$i] before using array_push**

```
for ($i ...) {
    for ($j ...) {
        for ($k ...) {
            if (!is_array($terms[$i])) $terms[$i] = array();
            // your stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

But I prefer the 1st solution...